# What is a Composite Word™?

Tags: pattern, language, number-theory, word-property

Here are some Composite Words™:

```
ADEPTIO           DIVTVRNVS
EXILIS            MIXTVM
CVLTELLVS         ARMARIVM
ACERBVS           ALIOQVI
IMPRAESENTIARVM   CVRVVS
AMICVS            CONCVLCO
LACRIMABILIS      ABVNDANS
ADDO              ADEO
IMMVNDVS          INFLECTVM
ALTVS             LIQVIDVS
```

Here are some non-Composite Words™:

```
ANTIQVVS          LVXVRIA
AMICVLVM          CRINITVS
ABSQVE            IVDICIVM
MVNIMENTVM        EXCELLENTIA
CALLIDE           ECCLESIA
AMICITIA          MAXIME
IMPRIMIS          ALIQVANTVS
HAFFLIGENIENSIS   INCLITVS
CALAMITAS         CONIVRATVS
BAIVLVS           ARTIFICIOSE
```

**What property determines if I call it a Composite Word™ or not?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Composite words are those where the

> sum of the Roman numeral values of the contained letters `IVXLCDM`

is equal to

> a composite number.

The relevant data for each word:

> `ADEPTIO 501 [3, 167]
>  DIVTVRNVS 516 [2, 2, 3, 43]
>  EXILIS 62 [2, 31]
>  MIXTVM 2016 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7]
>  CVLTELLVS 260 [2, 2, 5, 13]
>  ARMARIVM 2006 [2, 17, 59]
>  ACERBVS 105 [3, 5, 7]
>  ALIOQVI 57 [3, 19]
>  IMPRAESENTIARVM 2007 [3, 3, 223]
>  CVRVVS 115 [5, 23]
>  AMICVS 1106 [2, 7, 79]
>  CONCVLCO 355 [5, 71]
>  LACRIMABILIS 1203 [3, 401]
>  ABVNDANS 505 [5, 101]
>  ADDO 1000 [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
>  ADEO 500 [2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
>  IMMVNDVS 2511 [3, 3, 3, 3, 31]
>  INFLECTVM 1156 [2, 2, 17, 17]
>  ALTVS 55 [5, 11]
>  LIQVIDVS 562 [2, 281]
>  
>  ANTIQVVS 11 [11]
>  LVXVRIA 71 [71]
>  AMICVLVM 2161 [2161]
>  CRINITVS 107 [107]
>  ABSQVE 5 [5]
>  IVDICIVM 1613 [1613]
>  MVNIMENTVM 3011 [3011]
>  EXCELLENTIA 211 [211]
>  CALLIDE 701 [701]
>  ECCLESIA 251 [251]
>  AMICITIA 1103 [1103]
>  MAXIME 2011 [2011]
>  IMPRIMIS 2003 [2003]
>  ALIQVANTVS 61 [61]
>  HAFFLIGENIENSIS 53 [53]
>  INCLITVS 157 [157]
>  CALAMITAS 1151 [1151]
>  CONIVRATVS 111 [3, 37]
>  BAIVLVS 61 [61]
>  ARTIFICIOSE 103 [103]`

Comment: Ah, I thought the words had too many V,X and L's.

Comment: Nice work :) $ $

Comment: What is a composite number?

Comment: A number greater than 1 that isn't prime.

Comment: CONIVRATVS violates the rule