# What is a Decomposed Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word has a certain property, I call it a ***Decomposed Word™***.

You can use the examples below to find the property:

| Decomposed™ | Not Decomposed™ |
| --- | --- |
| JOINING | ADHERING |
| AGGRAVATE | EXACERBATE |
| ANNEXING | APPENDING |
| WATCHLIST | REGISTER |
| VANQUISHING | DEFEATING |
| PLAINTEXT | CLEARTEXT |
| DESEXUALIZE | EMASCULATE |
| MOCCASIN | SLIPPER |
| LITIGATION | LAWSUIT |
| MIX | STIR |
| CODIFY | TABULATE |
| METHAMPHETAMINE | OPIOID |
| CONQUERING | SUBJUGATING |

Here is a CSV version:

```
Decomposed™,Not Decomposed™
JOINING,ADHERING
AGGRAVATE,EXACERBATE
ANNEXING,APPENDING
WATCHLIST,REGISTER
VANQUISHING,DEFEATING
PLAINTEXT,CLEARTEXT
DESEXUALIZE,EMASCULATE
MOCCASIN,SLIPPER
LITIGATION,LAWSUIT
MIX,STIR
CODIFY,TABULATE
METHAMPHETAMINE,OPIOID
CONQUERING,SUBJUGATING
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Composite Word™?](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19982/what-is-a-composite-word)

Comment: @randal'thor I would argue it's different, since one has to do with the sum of the contained RNs, while the other contains only a single RN.  We can let the community decide, though.

Comment: @randal'thor I was not aware of the other question when I posted mine (or I probably wouldn't have posted it).

Comment: Yes, there's a *very* slight difference, but in most cases the two would come to the same thing. And the idea needed - the interesting part - is exactly the same ("think of Roman numerals"). They're both worthy of upvotes though, of course :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think Decomposed Words are

> those for which, if you extract the letters that are used for Roman numerals, make a prime number

and Not Decomposed Words are accordingly

> those which yield either a composite number or 1.

The given examples don't let us tell

> how to classify words that contain no such letters.

Per GentlePurpleRain's suggestion in comments: the name is because

> when you *decompose* a number as far as possible into factors, the components you end up with are the prime numbers (what about 1? I hear you cry; well, when you decompose 1 into factors you get *the empty set of factors*, all of whose elements are in fact prime).

And here are the actual values:

> `2 II   JOINING         |  501 DI  ADHERING
>     5 V    AGGRAVATE       |   90 XC  EXACERBATE
>    11 XI   ANNEXING        |  501 DI  APPENDING
>   151 CLI  WATCHLIST       |    1 I   REGISTER
>     7 VII  VANQUISHING     |  501 DI  DEFEATING
>    59 LIX  PLAINTEXT       |  160 CLX CLEARTEXT
>   541 DXLI DESEXUALIZE     | 1150 MCL EMASCULATE
>  1201 MCCI MOCCASIN        |   51 LI  SLIPPER
>    53 LIII LITIGATION      |   51 LI  LAWSUIT
>  1009 MIX  MIX             |    1 I   STIR
>   401 CDI  CODIFY          |   50 L   TABULATE
>  3001 MMMI METHAMPHETAMINE |  498 IID OPIOID
>   101 CI   CONQUERING      |    1 I   SUBJUGATING`

You may notice that the second-last one of those on the right

> is nonstandard because you can't really put *two* smaller "decrementing" Is before a single D. DII is also composite (of course; it's even and doesn't equal 2) but if we just add up Roman numerals without regard to position then MIX no longer works because MXI = 1011 which, being a multiple of 3, is not prime.

But the questioner indicates in comments that

> his intention was that anything not containing a valid Roman numeral should be a Not Decomposed Word, so OPIOID is fine for that reason.

Comment: those words are Decomposing

Comment: Perhaps you could flesh out your answer by providing a) some examples using the words provided above and b) an explanation of why they are called "decomposed"?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, done. I'm a little puzzled by OPIOID, but perhaps I'm just on drugs or something.

Comment: Wow! It wasn't my intention for the non-decomposed words to even generate anything valid at all.  I'm surprised that (just by chance) all but one of them did...

Comment: Ah, OK. Then I am no longer puzzled by OPIOID.